# Confusion about averaging using integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, average

I am stuck at one point and will appreciate if the community can guide me. I have a final expression as part my research which looks something like following:

$$I = \frac{X}{G(\gamma)}$$

where $G(\gamma) = 1+d\cos(\gamma)$ and $\gamma$ is the angle with which the Gain $G$ is defined and $d$ is the directivity.

Similarly, $X = \pi (\epsilon r)^{-\alpha}[\lambda_1(P_1)^{2/\alpha} + \kappa\lambda_2(P_2)^{2/\alpha}]$.

I want to take the average of Gain over angles $\gamma \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, I get  $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{G}{\pi} = 1+\frac{2d}{\pi}$. However, I am not sure if I can directly do this for $I$. Which one should I do

1. $I' = \frac{X}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{1+d\cos(\gamma)} d\gamma$
2. $I' = \frac{\pi X}{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} [1+d\cos(\gamma) ]d\gamma}$

Comment: What are you trying to average? Either one could be used in different contexts. The first one is the average of $I$, while the second uses the average of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\dfrac{X}{G(\gamma)}$$

If you want to take the average of Gain over angles $\gamma \in [\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$,then

$$\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}G.d\gamma =\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}[1+dcos(\gamma)]d\gamma=1+\dfrac{2d}{\pi} $$

If you want to take the average of $I$ over angles $\gamma \in [\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$,then

$$\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}I.d\gamma =\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{X}{1+dcos(\gamma)}d\gamma =\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{X}{1+dcos(\gamma)}d\gamma $$

Substituting $cos(\gamma)=\dfrac{1-tan^2(\gamma /2)}{1+tan^2(\gamma /2)}$, and taking $tan(\gamma /2)=t$

$$\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{X}{1+d\dfrac{1-tan^2(\gamma /2)}{1+tan^2(\gamma /2)}}d\gamma=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2X}{(1+d)+(1-d)t^2}dt$$$$=\dfrac{4X}{\pi\sqrt{(1+d)(1-d)}} \arctan(\sqrt{\dfrac{1-d}{1+d}}) $$

If you want to calculate $I$ with the averaged value of Gain, then

$$I=\dfrac{X}{1+\dfrac{2d}{\pi}}$$

EDIT:

$d$ is antenna directivity, and is always $\geq 1$.

$$=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2X}{(1+d)+(1-d)t^2}dt=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2X}{(d+1)-(d-1)t^2}dt$$.$$=\dfrac{2}{\pi(d-1)}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2X}{\dfrac{d+1}{d-1}-t^2}dt=\dfrac{2X}{\pi\sqrt{(d+1)(d-1)}}ln\dfrac{\sqrt{d+1}+\sqrt{d-1}}{\sqrt{d+1}-\sqrt{d-1}}$$

Comment: Can you please let me know how the limits changeed from $[-\pi/2 , \pi/2]$ to $[0,\pi/2]$ ?

Comment: By symmetry about $\gamma=0$; $1+d\cos(-\gamma)=1+d\cos\gamma$, so the integral over $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ is equal to twice the integral over $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: One more thing, since $d$ is the directivity of an antenna, if it is more than 1, then the result with $arctan$ term in the above answer is not valid, as $1-d<0$. In this case, solve the integral by taking the denominator of the integral as $a^2-x^2=(a+x)(a-x)$ and solve it by applying partial fraction method.

Answer (score 0):

I think what @NarendraDeconda did is right.

Just one comment for @shanjaff.

It seems $I$ is a final expression for a system output.
If that is the case and you want to observe the effect of $G$ on the system, then use the option (2).

Else, if you want to use the averaged value of Gain, then use the option (1).

Comment: Yes, I wanted to see the effect of $G$ over $I$. And yes, $I$ gives me output for a system. Thanks.